# Associate an event listener on a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
 <div class="ui-content">
        <ul class="ui-listview">
            <li class="li-has-radio">
                <label>
                    15 mn
                    <input type="radio" value="15" name="radSize" checked="checked"/>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li class="li-has-radio">
                <label>
                    30 mn
                    <input type="radio" value="30" name="radSize"/>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li class="li-has-radio">
                <label>
                    45 mn
                    <input type="radio" value="45" name="radSize"/>
                </label>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

And when I have an event listener on the click on each button like this:

```
$("#inline_content input[name='radSize']").on('change', function(){
alert('You clicked radio!');
    var mytime = $('input:radio[name=radSize]:checked').val();
    alert($('input:radio[name=radSize]:checked').val());
    window.open("categorie.html?temps="+mytime);
});
```

Everything works fine except for the first radio button, it's checked by default but when I clicked on it nothing happen.

What should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Just don't select it by default?

Comment: Well, yeah, because the value doesn't change.

Comment: if it's already checked and you click on it there is no change. Also user not likely to click on it either for same reason.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that a selected radio button doesn't change when you click on it. I'd recommend either switching to a `click` handler (instead of change) or else using buttons instead of radios.

Of course, with buttons, you'll also need a click handler.

If you want to keep things more similar to what you have now, starting off with the first radio unselected will also resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use click event:

```
$("input[name='radSize']").on('click', function(){
alert('You clicked radio!');
    var mytime = $('input:radio[name=radSize]:checked').val();
    alert($('input:radio[name=radSize]:checked').val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p3C8L/